# Mongodb with php can't use where query

Tags: php, mongodb

I have been install Mongodb v.2.6.7 with php mongo driver v.1.6.3
When I get data all it work normally but if I use where query It return empty array back to me.

Comment: Thank Neil Lunn, Now my problem is fixed but now it have other error with limit(1) it return result array empty but when i use limit(2) the return result is correct to me i don know why? below is my code to use:
$resutl = $this->mongo_db->limit(1)->get('UserProfile');

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'phpmanual');

// search for documents where 5 < x < 20
$rangeQuery = array('x' => array( '$gt' => 5, '$lt' => 20 ));

$cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)